# How to expand IPv6 address in C

Tags: c

I want to expand my IPv6 address.Is there any way to expand that address to a full one?
If I get abcd:12::7 then I need to expand it to abcd:0012:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0007
mainly for incrementating the address.

I already written some code but shows an error.The error is - "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'arpa/inet.h': No such file or directory".I am using visual studio 2005.

Comment: Questions that look like orders don't work very well on this site. Try posting what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

For any kind of IPv6 address manipulation, you'll need to store it as an array of 4 unsigned ints (4bytes each). Most stacks store it somewhat like this, this is from the linux kernel:

```
 struct in6_addr {
         union {
                 __u8            u6_addr8[16];
                 __be16          u6_addr16[8];
                 __be32          u6_addr32[4];
         } in6_u;
 #define s6_addr                 in6_u.u6_addr8
 #define s6_addr16               in6_u.u6_addr16
 #define s6_addr32               in6_u.u6_addr32
 };
```

You'll need to convert your string to this packed format using `inet_pton()`.

Comment: My code is -                                                 #include "stdafx.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "arpa/inet.h"

int _tmain(int argc, char argv[])
{

struct in6_addr {
unsigned char   s6_addr[16];   // IPv6 address
};
struct in6_addr ipv6;
char str[]="abcd:1234::ffff";
if(strcnt(str,":")>1)
{
 if(inet_pton(AF_INET6,str,&ipv6.s6_addr))
  printf("%s is %0llu(IPv6)\n",str,ipv6.s6_addr);
 else
  printf("Error..");
}

getch();

return 0;
 
}